# Trying to track down a vague error in apache logs

Tags: php, apache2

I am trying to stamp out errors on a new Ubuntu server install and am getting errors in the logs that I have no clue on how to track down.

The logs show this line over and over

```
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ~
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ~
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ~
sh: 1: cd: can't cd to ~
```

How do I find the source from such a vague error? It does not even have a time of occurrence that most errors in the logs have.

Thanks in advance. It is going to be a long day!

Comment: Do the lines you showed represent the WHOLE log line?  That is, there is no timestamp at the beginning?

Comment: That is correct. Those are the log lines in their entirety.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cd ~` means "change the directory I'm in to my home directory". Either you, or a script is trying to unsuccesfully run this command. Like Chris said, a grep will save your day:

```
cd /
grep -r 'cd ~' * -n
```

^this will switch to your root directory `cd /`, recursively `-r` search for the string `'cd ~'` in all files `*`, and also give the line number `-n`

Comment: Yeah I gathered that much. Finding the offending script is my problem.

Comment: I may have found the offending script with this command. I will come back with more details and mark this an answer if it turns out to be the problem.

Comment: Ok, the problem was that a Symfony2 vendor package aws-sdk-for-php was looking for a config file that the creator neglected to include so I just created the missing file config.inc.php in the package root. The problem is detailed here http://blog.isnoop.net/2012/04/02/cd-1-cant-cd-to/ . It would have been nice if that page showed up in google since I searched for the error...

Comment: Hopefully they'll accept this patch: https://github.com/meonkeys/aws-sdk-for-php/commit/14ce5605499108d23a93601c1939182c9a81f14d

Comment: FYI: This is was fixed in [Amazon SDK 1.5.15](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/blob/1.5.15/sdk.class.php)

Answer (score 0):

maybe grep for files containing the string `cd` whos last access time was recent